# i have locked myself out of my drupal site

Tags: drupal-6

i have stupidly managed to lock myself out of my own drupal site.
i have deleted my browser cookies while my page.tpl.php doesnt print the login form.
when i change my page.tpl.php file to print the log in form, i doesn't, cause the theme registry is not cleared.
i cant clear it - i am not the admin.
nice look up, isnt it ?
my thoughts are to manually modify my data base, but i took a look at it, and it will take me hours to understand what i need to do without causing harm.
can someone help me unlock myself ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, got the answer from the drupal forum.
http://www.yoursite.com/user
does the trick, cause the login form comes in the content area and not the unvisable block view.